# Alternative datastore per request type on sails.js

Tags: sails.js

In a sails.js project, I would like to use a different database endpoint for READ operations (using AWS RDS read replica) than the default datastore that I will keep using for WRITE operations.

As explained [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-models), it is possible in sails.js to set datastore on a per-model basis, but what about setting an alternative datastore on a per-request basis or directly for all read operations?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this in a Sails-y fashion, would be to have "read only" models. This does a couple things: first, will make it very clear which datastore you are working with in your controllers, if you have say a `User` model, and a `UserRead` model, and that means it doubles your models (small price to pay in memory costs); but, this also means Sails can easily manage your read only and write databases, you just have to be conscience of using the proper model in the proper context.

To keep things really light in your duplicate "read only" model (and so you don't have to change 2 models every time something changes), you could just extend your original model, and simply change the `datastore`, something like this should work:

**UserRead.js**

```js
module.exports = _.merge({}, require('./User'), {datastore: 'defaultRead'});
```